# UITableViewCell with dynamic number of UILables

Tags: ios, dynamic, uitableview, uilabel, automatic-ref-counting

I was trying to implement a tableview like this one

please read the comment to see the link <1>

My implementation is:
1. i create my cell from a nib!
please read the comment to see the link <2>

1. For testing purpose i hardcode the heading part of the cell, and i create the rest in the code like this ...

   ```
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:                (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
       UITableViewCell *myCell = (UITableViewCell*) 
       [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CheckedOutOrderTableCell"];

       [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CheckedOutOrderTableCell" owner:self options:NULL];
       myCell = nibLoadedTableCell;

       UILabel *orderConditionLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(250, (85+([[bigDictionary objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]count]*35)), 64, 21)];
       [orderConditionLabel setText:@"Delivered"];
       [orderConditionLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];
       orderConditionLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
       orderConditionLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

       for(NSInteger i=0; i<[[bigDictionary objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]count]; i++)
       {
           UILabel *quantityLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 85+(i*35), 42, 21)];  
           UILabel *foodLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(85, 85+(i*35), 175, 21)];
           UILabel *priceLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(220, 85+(i*35), 60, 21)];

           [quantityLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15]];
           [foodLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15]];
           [priceLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15]];

           [quantityLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[[bigDictionary objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"quantity"]]];           
           [foodLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[[bigDictionary objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"item_name"]]];        
           [priceLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"$ %@.00", [[[bigDictionary objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"price"]]];   

           [self.view addSubview:quantityLabel];
           [self.view addSubview:foodLabel];
           [self.view addSubview:priceLabel]; 
           quantityLabel = nil;
           foodLabel = nil;
           priceLabel = nil;
       }
       [self.view addSubview:orderConditionLabel];
       orderConditionLabel = nil;
       return myCell;
   }
   ```
2. and of course i also rewrite heightForRowAtIndexPath: and i finally got this one...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cF7Y4.png

1. everything seems going right :D  all the label are dynamic created and the position goes perfect... then i tried to save any other record.... and got crashed :'(

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAXMF.png

1. I check the data I fed into those cells using NSLOG and below is the structure of my "bigDictionary"

   ```
   2012-05-17 12:17:50.330 LazBuy[53187:11903] show structure (
           (
                   {
               "item_name" = "\U8292\U679c\U9752\U8336";
               price = 30;
               quantity = 1;
           },
                   {
               "item_name" = "\U6587\U5c71\U6e05\U8336";
               price = 20;
               quantity = 3;
           },
                   {
               "item_name" = "\U8292\U679c\U9752\U8336";
               price = 30;
               quantity = 3;
           }
       ),
           (
                   {
               "item_name" = "\U51cd\U9802\U70cf\U9f8d\U8336";
               price = 15;
               quantity = 3;
           }
       )
   )
   ```
2. The data are fed properly, I do not know what is going wrong!

Why the label didnt update properly, do I need to release them? But I cant release as ARC do not let me do the release line.

Comment: link2 : http://i.stack.imgur.com/92Cra.png

Comment: you want to extend uitableviewcell dynamically?

Comment: yes!!! any ideas how to implement it.. in a nicer/ beautiful way :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding the labels to self.view? Theses should be on the tableviewcell.

```
[self.view addSubview:quantityLabel];
[self.view addSubview:foodLabel];
[self.view addSubview:priceLabel];
```

and

```
[self.view addSubview:orderConditionLabel];
```

Also your tableviewcell reuse should look more like this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
 static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TVCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = tvCell;
        self.tvCell = nil;
    }

    // Set your labels text

    return cell;
}
```